# Dividing periods by cut date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Could you please take a look at the following task?

I have the following dataset:

[image]

Here is script for this data:

```
;with dataset AS (
    select 'EMP01' AS EMP_ID,CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE) AS PERIOD_START,CAST('2018-01-31' AS DATE) AS PERIOD_END,CAST('2018-01-07' AS DATE) AS CUT_DATE
    UNION
    select 'EMP01' AS EMP_ID,CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE) AS PERIOD_START,CAST('2018-01-31' AS DATE) AS PERIOD_END,CAST('2018-01-15' AS DATE) AS CUT_DATE
    UNION
    select 'EMP02' AS EMP_ID,CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE) AS PERIOD_START,CAST('2018-01-31' AS DATE) AS PERIOD_END,CAST('2018-01-09' AS DATE) AS CUT_DATE
)
select *
from dataset
```

I need to divide these periods (PERIOD_START and PERIOD_END) by CUT_DATE (exclude cut dates from that periods) The number of cut dates could be any (3,5,8 etc).

Expecting result for the dataset above is:

[image]

Comment: Why do you have multiple rows per employee?  That makes the question very confusing.  What happens if the start and end dates are not the same, for instance?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Gordon. Start Date and End Date will always be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
with dataset AS (
    select 'EMP01' AS EMP_ID,CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE) AS PERIOD_START,CAST('2018-01-31' AS DATE) AS PERIOD_END,CAST('2018-01-07' AS DATE) AS CUT_DATE
    UNION
    select 'EMP01' AS EMP_ID,CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE) AS PERIOD_START,CAST('2018-01-31' AS DATE) AS PERIOD_END,CAST('2018-01-15' AS DATE) AS CUT_DATE
    UNION
    select 'EMP02' AS EMP_ID,CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE) AS PERIOD_START,CAST('2018-01-31' AS DATE) AS PERIOD_END,CAST('2018-01-09' AS DATE) AS CUT_DATE
)
select emp_id, period_start period_start, cut_date - 1 period_end from dataset
union all
select emp_id, cut_date + 1 period_start, period_end period_end from dataset;
```

Comment: You have clearly not actually tested this code.  It would not provide the output required by this question even if you did fix the syntax errors.

Comment: I have tested it and received needed result.Query is correct. Still, I tested it on static table, not dynamic dataset, because exact dynamic dataset of a thread starter isn't working for me. I bet you too have errors in dataset, not in my query.

Comment: Hi Dave and Dmitriy. Dave is right, it will work only if we have one cut date for employee. However, as showed above - we can have multiple cut dates for simgle period.

Comment: @dmitriy-yankin  For starters, you cannot apply `-1` operators to `date` data types.

Comment: Actually you can in Oracle SQL that I used to test it, but I see my logic error about cut dates. I didn't get question right. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: *Actually you can in Oracle SQL*  -- Which is irrelevant to this question, which is regarding SQL Server...

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using a dates table and window functions.  If you don't have a dates table, you can generate one for this query using the first two `cte` tables in the script below:

```
declare @t table(emp_id nvarchar(10)
                ,period_start date
                ,period_end date
                ,cut_date date
                );
insert into @t values
 ('EMP01','20180101','20180131','2018-01-07')
,('EMP01','20180101','20180131','2018-01-15')
,('EMP02','20180101','20180131','2018-01-09')
;

declare @s date = (select min(period_start) as d from @t);
declare @e date = (select max(period_end) as d from @t);

              -- Generate a table of 10 rows
with t(t) as (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1)
    ,d(d) as (select top (select datediff(day,@s,@e)+1) dateadd(day,row_number() over (order by (select null))-1,@s) from t t1,t t2,t t3,t t4,t t5)  -- CROSS JOIN 10 rows together 5 times for a maximum of 10*10*10*10*10 = 100,000 rows
    ,c    as (select d.d
                    ,t.emp_id
                    ,t.period_start
                    ,t.period_end
                    ,sum(case when t.cut_date = d.d then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by t.emp_id order by d.d) as p
              from @t as t
                  left join d
                      on(d.d between t.period_start and t.period_end)
             )
select emp_id
      ,min(case when period_start = d then d else dateadd(day,1,d) end) as period_start
      ,max(d) as period_end
from c
group by emp_id
        ,p
order by emp_id
        ,period_start
```

Output:

```
+--------+--------------+------------+
| emp_id | period_start | period_end |
+--------+--------------+------------+
| EMP01  | 2018-01-01   | 2018-01-06 |
| EMP01  | 2018-01-08   | 2018-01-14 |
| EMP01  | 2018-01-16   | 2018-01-31 |
| EMP02  | 2018-01-01   | 2018-01-08 |
| EMP02  | 2018-01-10   | 2018-01-31 |
+--------+--------------+------------+
```

Comment: @DavidFreeman  No worries :)  If this was the correct answer for your question, please mark it as such for others that may have the same problem.